# A comunidade quer ter moderadores próprios?

Tags: debate, comunidade, moderação

Como sabem os sites da rede SE têm moderadores. No nosso caso temos a
sorte de ter um gerente de comunidade  exclusivo, ie que é dedicado ao nosso
pt.stackoverflow.com, o [Gabe](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/12/gabe).
A SE ter-nos dado um gerente de comunidade é excelente e este post não é sobre
esse aspecto nem sobre avaliar a participação e contributo do [Gabe](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/12/gabe) para a
nossa comunidade.

A vantagem de ter mais moderadores é poder ter sempre algum moderador
online que possa melhorar posts, dar conselhos no momento em que
dúvidas surgem, lembrar e encorajar discussões de novos tópicos no
meta e ajudar novos utilizadores.

O Gabe não está sempre online e por vezes passam varios dias sem que
ele possa estar presente. Para além disso, a nossa comunidade tem fusos horários diferentes e se tivermos mais moderadores aumentamos a presença online do papel do moderador.

Eu gostava de ver moderador(es) escolhido(s) pela comunidade.

A meu ver o moderador não deve ser aquele que decide o caminho de um
discussão nem impõe as regras da comunidade, isso faz-se aqui no Meta, por todos.
No caso do Gabe, uma vez que é também representante da SE, ele pode
ter directivas para a comunidade. Esta tambem não é a razão deste
post.

Sinto falta de uma outra faceta, outro aspecto: um moderador escolhido
pela comunidade. Alguem que se juntou ao SOpt porque quer aprender e
contribuir. Porque quer fazer parte da comunidade. Ver tal pessoa
escolhida é uma realização para a comunidade. Esse passo está a
faltar.

Essa(s) pessoa(s) terão um respeito e carinho especial e acho que isso
estimula a comunidade e dá um sentido novo de responsabilidade e
participação a todos. Tal posição não pode por defenição ser preenchida pelo Gabe.

**Esta é a minha opinião** e o que eu gostava de ver acontecer.
**Seria interessante ter a *vossa* opinião** em respostas diferentes (em baixo).

Comment: Eu concordo que seria bons termos moderadores que não façam parte do staff da Stack Exchange. Mas não acho que a comunidade esteja grande e madura o suficiente para ter eleições. Então, seria o caso da SE escolher esses moderadores. Lembrando que na última vez que eles se posicionaram quanto a isso, disseram que consideravam desnecessário.

Comment: A comunidade ainda não estar grande ou madura (e não discordo disso) näo deve servir como razão para fechar esse papel a elementos da comunidade. A figura de moderador temporário existe e podia ser usada aqui também à semelhança dos outros novos sites da SE.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### A comunidade quer ter moderadores próprios?

Difícil alguém responder *não* para isso, não acham? A questão aqui, no fundo, é por que não temos outros moderadores até agora, e quando os teremos. E as respostas oficiais já foram dadas: não temos ainda porque "o nosso site é diferente" e porque "por enquanto não há necessidade", e os teremos "em breve", "quando chegar a hora". Entendeu?

### O que é moderação

"Moderação", no contexto dos sites da Stack Exchange, é um conceito que envolve toda a comunidade, e não apenas os usuários com um diamante ♦ no nome, a quem chamamos de "moderadores". As tarefas de moderação, incluindo as que só moderadores com o diamante podem realizar, são de dois tipos:

- **Arrumar a casa:** editar publicações, classificar perguntas, orientar usuários usando comentários, votar para fechar ou reabrir, sinalizar, participar de discussões no meta, entre outras.
- **Tratar exceções:** tomar a decisão final quanto aos posts sinalizados, suspender, fundir e mesclar usuários, detectar esquemas de spam ou fraude de votos, lidar com trolls e outros tipos problemáticos de usuário por mensagens privadas, entre outras.

O tratamento de exceções depende quase integralmente das ferramentas que somente os moderadores com diamante possuem, enquanto arrumar a casa permite uma participação maior da comunidade – embora certas operações dependam dos moderadores, ou possam ser realizadas por eles com mais facilidade/agilidade.

### Como é a moderação no nosso site?

Nosso moderador foca seu trabalho no tratamento de exceções. Considerando isso, talvez um único moderador seja suficiente. Na verdade não temos como julgar, pois o único indicador que vemos desse tipo de atividade é o número de flags pendentes caindo (às vezes mais lentamente do que esperávamos), ou um ou outro usuário suspenso com o qual esbarramos. Esse é um tipo de tarefa, por definição, sigilosa. E mesmo que um único moderador dê conta dela no momento, isso não deve durar muito tempo.

Mas e a outra parte, a arrumação da casa? A Stack Exchange *optou* por influir pouco nisso, deixar o site e a comunidade se desenvolverem de maneira orgânica. A comunidade já faz sozinha uma parte da arrumação da casa, vemos isso acontecendo diariamente. O que depende das ferramentas que só os moderadores têm é delegado ao Gabe, por meio de sinalizações ou debates no meta, e fica dependendo da opinião da SE e da disponibilidade do Gabe. Então, se por um lado a comunidade tem liberdade e não sofre grandes imposições oficiais, por outro falta a ela um bocado de autonomia, visto que suas posições precisam sempre ser legitimadas pela Stack Exchange.

### Como deveria ser

A comunidade definitivamente poderia fazer mais se alguns membros fossem moderadores. Eu não acho que o tratamento de exceções seja a única função dos moderadores, especialmente num site ainda novo e pequeno como o nosso. Para mim, moderação é o pacote completo. Neste momento, é importante ter moderadores ajudando a dar o exemplo para a comunidade, editando, comentando, participando do meta (atendendo pedidos de suporte, propondo e participando de debates interessantes, etc.), e inclusive votando nas perguntas e respostas do site.

Eu já cobrei do Gabe que ele participasse mais da arrumação da casa, e de fato ele passou a participar mais, mas ainda me parece pouco. E agora estou achando que cobrei errado. O papel dele não é ser um membro da comunidade como os outros. O envolvimento dele não foi espontâneo, ele é o Gerente da Comunidade, um funcionário da SE. Ele tem outras obrigações que não fazem parte do universo dos moderadores "comuns" dos demais sites; seu trabalho, acredito, envolve tarefas que vão além da moderação.

Eu gostaria de ver uma aproximação maior entre comunidade e moderação, e entre a comunidade e a própria Stack Exchange. Isso *requer* moderadores que sejam membros da comunidade, pois o acúmulo de funções do Gabe o deixa num papel ambíguo. Não que a comunidade assim passaria a ter recursos para impor o que quisesse à SE, muito pelo contrário – engana-se quem acha que isto aqui é ou um dia será uma democracia. Mas acredito que ambas as partes tenham mais interesses comuns que conflitantes, especialmente ver o site crescer e produzir conteúdo de qualidade. E os interesses conflitantes, quando surgirem, certamente serão debatidos antes que qualquer lado tome alguma atitude mais drástica.

### Conclusão: um moderador não é suficiente

Mas não simplesmente pela quantidade de trabalho, e sim pelo ganho de autonomia que outro moderador representaria para a comunidade. Seria muito benéfico que houvesse uma *equipe* de moderação, que debatesse as questões pertinentes à atividade, e que fosse capaz de atuar em horários diversificados.

E mais, mesmo que um moderador pudesse resolver tudo sozinho, que mal faria ter outros? Dividir o trabalho não seria uma ajuda bem-vinda?

Comment: O que mais concordei foi o que disse sobre o papel do Gabe. Não faz sentido desviarmos seu trabalho para fazer o trabalho necessário da moderação. Também creio que a necessidade de moderadores fica clara com mais tempo. O pessoal está um pouco impaciente, só isso.

Comment: Excelente resumo da situação. Especialmente do envolvimento do Community Manager, pôxa, o Gabe apesar de membro do SO há 5 anos tem [pouco mais de mil pontos](http://stackexchange.com/users/5960/gabe?tab=accounts) de reputação somando todos os sites da rede (restando a reputação por associação). Um moderador normal é alguém que passa o dia com a bunda na cadeira, o olho na tela e mais de uma tab Stack no browser. Que responde rápido e sabe o que está acontecendo entre perguntas, respostas, análises, Meta e Chat. Tudo bem, dá pra esperar, mas me parece fundamental pro fluxo das coisas.

Comment: Bom ver o diamante no seu nome! Resposta aceite :)

Comment: Obrigado @Sergio! Estou na dúvida se esta pergunta é um caso para [meta-tag:status-pronto], já que não é um pedido e sim um debate.

Comment: @bfavaretto concordo. Se pode colocar por mim parece-me correto!

Answer (score 5):

Acredito que realmente iria contribuir bastante para a comunidade, não só uma pessoa mas um grupo de moderadores que poderiam auxiliar de diversas formas como quando eu entrei na SOpt, cometi erros que vi vários novatos cometerem, no meu caso aparecerem dois tipos de pessoas, umas que só criticaram(não vou citar nomes) e outras que auxiliaram e fizeram o legitimo papel de um moderador, apontaram o caminho correto a se seguir e uma dessas pessoas [@bfavaretto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/74/bfavaretto) merece ter o nome citado pois agiu da forma como deve se agir ao ver um novo membro cometendo erros dentro da comunidade.

Answer (score 4):

Acho que isso apenas depende da SE liberar a eleição para esta instância. Já existe até um tópico das pessoas lançando candidatura.

Resta saber o que devemos fazer para que o mecanismo de eleição automática seja liberado.

Comment: Não é bem isso. Aquele tópico da indicação dos moderadores foi deliberadamente ignorado pela Stack Exchange.

Comment: Então precisamos entender como comover a Stack Exchange a levar em consideração a vontade da comunidade.

Answer (score 3):

O fato do ter eleições por votos populares, acho muito interessante, porque isso ajuda a comunidade a conhecer um pouco melhor os indicados e geralmente ver aqueles que possuem uma certa atividade no SOpt incentiva a esses escolhidos a continuarem com o bom trabalho.

Outra idéia que acho interessante, seria indicação de moderadores por Tags ou Grupo de Tags

O fato de estar maduro ou não, não é um empecilho, vejo que é o contrário porque assim a comunidade inteira, mais ou menos, sabe como é a posição dos envolvidos nas eleições, conseguem acompanhar mais de perto.