# Estado da Pilha #1: Carinho

Tags: debate

> Na falta de uma newsletter, vamos tentar algo diferente... Eu não sei muito bem o que vai ser disso, mas me parece uma boa ideia no momento.
>
> <sup>PS: Eu raramente tenho boas ideias.</sup>

### Como estamos?

O site cresce; O site vai bem; O site é a melhor coisa que já aconteceu na área de perguntas e respostas sobre programação em Português!

- **8,4k** usuários
- **4,5k** perguntas
- **37** perguntas/dia

Se você não sabe o que esses números significam, basta visitar [nossa lista de sites](http://stackexchange.com/sites) e ver que, mesmo com 5 meses de idade, temos mais perguntas por dia que o Programmers SE, mais usuários que o Christianity SE e mais perguntas que o Academia SE. Todos esses sites graduados e com **anos** de vida.

O SOPT é um dos sites de crescimento mais rápido que já tivemos, e todos estão de parabéns!

---

### Essa semana, no SOPT...

Algumas coisas chamaram minha atenção na semana passada, que eu gostaria de falar aqui, mas que não são reclamações sobre a forma como a comunidade vem gerenciando a si mesma. São sim, coisas que ocorrem que talvez possam melhorar, para garantir que o nosso site continue saudável.

Houve alguns casos recentemente de reclamações do site ser muito rígido, autoritário, etc. Isso me fez pensar na primeira imagem que nós passamos aos recém-chegados. Não em termos de regras, mas sim de comportamento.

É esperado que o SOPT seja composto principalmente de pessoas que *não conhecem* o Stack Overflow, que não tem idéia de como o modelo funciona e, principalmente, **porque ele funciona**. Essas pessoas, então, precisam de tempo para aprender, precisam ser guiadas. Precisam de espaço para cometer erros e aprender com eles. E talvez nós possamos ser melhores nisso.

Eu, por exemplo, sempre gostei da ideia de ensinar através de edições (removendo cumprimentos, formatando código, melhorando o texto). Foi algo que aconteceu comigo quando comecei a usar o SO (5 anos atrás) e que apreciei na época. Era uma forma de me ensinar sem ter que me chamar a atenção.

Botei isso em prática no SOPT, preferindo editar à deixar um comentário chamando a atenção e esperando que o autor corrigisse. Até que vi alguém dizendo no Meta que considerava isso invasivo e autoritário. Então talvez minha impressão de que esse método é efetivo esteja errada...

Talvez seja melhor apenas o comentario? Talvez seja melhor editar **e** comentar? Talvez seja melhor permitir algumas coisas a mais no nosso primeiro ano? Não sei.

O que eu quero dizer é que o iniciante de hoje é o Jon Skeet de amanhã, e precisamos que as pessoas sejam bem recebidas aqui. Como podemos melhorar isso? Talvez alguém que começou agora pode dar uma impressão de como é chegar no SOPT.

Ser receptivo não tem nada a ver com permitir tudo no site, mas sim com como nós passamos as nossas regras, como fazemos para que nosso modelo seja entendido e respeitado por todos.

Onde podemos melhorar?

Comment: Muito bom! As vezes pensamos que o site está mais maduro do que está e queremos dar o passo maior do que a perna. Precisamos nos lembrar que ainda estamos nascendo, 5 meses não é nada para todo o tempo que teremos pela frente, portanto, não devemos engrossar as regras assim tão depressa, principalmente com os novatos. Só uma observação, os termos "invasivos" e "autoritários" eu usei em uma resposta minha que eu disse que _acho_ que esses podem ser os motivos que algumas pessoas reclamam das edições, mas ninguém confirmou se são esses os sentimentos mesmo.

Comment: @Gabe nada a dizer, o SOPT está cada vez melhor e acho que estamos no bom caminho.

Comment: Pelo visto os usuários mais novos, ou menos experientes, não sabem que existe o meta, nenhum se manifestou ainda...

Comment: "sempre gostei da ideia de ensinar através de edições" - e aproveitar o Resumo de Edição pra passar o recado também. . . . Oh, yeah, os números do site são show de bola!

Comment: Você tem como mensurar, nem que seja na base do *feeling*, a quantidade de reclamações relacionadas a rigidez, autoritarismo, etc? Foi só naquele momento? Tem sempre? Eu queria entender melhor o tamanho do problema (tenho certeza de que não é igual ao SO, onde isso é um problema mais sério, e já foi pior). Porque sempre vai ter gente não gostando que editemos, assim como vai ter gente não gostando que deixemos de editar... E depois dessa discussão toda eu tentei mudar de postura e confesso que fiquei meio perdido.

Comment: @bfavaretto Na base do feeling, eu diria que o número vem crescendo mas é certamente pequeno. Eu ainda preciso olhar esse post, mas gostaria de deixar bem claro que as coisas nele não são necessariamente "reclamações" minhas em relação ao site, mas sim coisas que me passaram pela cabeça durante a semana.

Answer (score 13):

Gostei do post, algo assim nunca é demais.

Só me surpreendeu que possa existir a possibilidade, mesmo que eventual, do site precisar recuar. Eu achava que o site está em um estado tão bom, mas tão bom, que um recuo já podia ser considerado impossível. A única possibilidade que via de algo drástico era a inversão da filosofia e o site virar um fórum. Mas isso não tem como acontecer.

Eu entendo a visão dos novatos. Não sei o que fazer porque não existe um grupo de novatos que agem igualmente. **Cada um tem sua visão**. Como mudar homogeneamente a percepção de pessoas heterogêneas? Não sei. Acho que não é possível. Você escolhe um grupo e lida o melhor possível com ele. Como agradar o usuário que quer que comentem o que ele errou e ao mesmo tempo agradar o que acha o comentário ensinando ele algo abusivo? E nem vou falar dos outros usuários que querem outra coisa ou os usuários que já se integraram à comunidade.

Legal, este post é sobre novatos. Mas será que também não precisamos olhar para os usuários experientes no SO ou outro site do SE e tentar entender porque eles circularam aqui por um ou dois dias e nunca mais voltaram? Ou as maiores autoridades que falam português em determinadas tecnologias que fizeram o cadastro, circularam aqui, eventualmente deram uma resposta e **decidiram que não querem participar**. Não estou especulando sobre isso.

Será que é por isso que não conseguimos bons resultados na métrica de média de respostas por pergunta? Ou será que é porque há muitas perguntas "helpdesk*? Isso vai afetar a avaliação do site? Ou já era esperado que fosse assim e o número não vai prejudicar nada?

Também acho que algumas coisas podem melhorar, mas no itens apresentados eu não sei se tem solução. Não há como agradar a todos. Mas se há, gostaria que alguém apresentasse uma **solução concreta**. Eu, por exemplo, só consigo melhorar em algo que não sei como lidar melhor, quando um *feedback* com uma solução concreta é apresentada.

Comment: Como assim "recuar"?

Comment: Ser encerrado, ser redefinido por completo, começar de novo. Eu sei que não deve ser o caso, eu entendi o que você escreveu. Mas a ideia que ele precisa de carinho extra, passa a *percepção* que se não houver esse carinho ele possa regredir de alguma forma, que se nem tudo estiver perfeito, ele precise ser repensado. Reforço, eu sei que não é o caso.

Comment: Quando eu falei de carinho, não quis dizer que o SOPT precisa de carinho, mas que ele precisa *ter carinho* com os novatos. Não faço ideia do que precisaria acontecer para que o SOPT fosse fechado de alguma forma, mas teria que ser catastrófico. Se passei a impressão de que isso poderia ocorrer, certamente não foi minha intenção.

Comment: Entendi. Então acho que estava influenciado por isso: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/15485702#15485702. Não passou a ideia errada. Eu disse que não achava que havia risco de fato. Também não faço ideia o que precisaria acontecer para que algo drástico acontecesse.

Comment: Em relação pergunta http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/15993/mapear-caminho-de-outro-projeto eu acabei editando antes do seu comentário e Fiquei em dúvida quanto a reverter ou não a edição. A prática adotada ficou definida?

Comment: @Caputo nada ficou definido e isso é um problema. Mas deixe a edição, ela não está errada. Na verdade só sabemos que temos que melhorar, não sabemos como.

Answer (score 13):

Eu acho que estes pontos ajudariam:

- Explicar insistentemente, com educação e cordialidade que determinadas ações são normais, que fechamento não é castigo, que -1 não significa que não gostamos do autor, que comentários são para ajudar a pessoa melhorar.

  Parte dos comportamentos "estranhos" me parece que é alimentada pela própria repetição inconsequente de que todo mundo é autoritário, que tem panela, etc. Isto só alimenta o senso de revolta de quem já está predisposto a encrenca, e tira o usuário do foco: aprender a ferramenta. Se o usuário aprende que aquela reação aparentemente negativa é normal, tem menos chance de levar pro lado pessoal e procurar pelo em ovo.
- Procurar fazer um comentário antes de "botar a mão na massa", e botar a mão na massa se houver inércia do autor. Com um tempo razoável para o autor ter tempo de entender o que está havendo.

  Quando não vai mudar o sentido, esse tempo pode ser mais curto, mas se for alterar a estrutura do que foi dito, compensa dar uma chance maior para o autor fazer da maneira que achar mais correta.
- Quando se tratar de problemas na questão, sugerir ao autor a ler as referências de "como perguntar" para que possa trabalhar melhor a questão.
- Dar tempo suficiente para o autor melhorar a questão antes de votar para fechar, quando a questão puder ser salva.

  Isso inclui ter boa vontade ao analisar se a pergunta tem salvação.
- Em especial indicar o help do markdown e sugerir a pessoa a seguir (acho que fazemos muito pouco este ítem em especial). Acredito que muita gente não formate certo por puro desconhecimento, e não falta de vontade.
- Se nada disso resolver, também não adianta querer moldar o SOpt para atender o comportamento daqueles que não vão deixar legado para o site. O legado conta, e muito.

> O Jon Skeet de amanhã só vai ser o Jon Skeet de amanhã se usar a ferramenta corretamente.

<sub>Se eu lembrar de algo, acrescento.</sub>

Comment: Acho que seria interessante ter alguns comentários enlatados bem elucidaditos e bem educados para algumas situações destas. Um dos motivos que eu acho que faltam comentários é que dá trabalho escrever algo do zero todas as vezes. O enlatado também evita a pessoa expressar insatisfação mesmo sem perceber. O que ainda não sei é o que fazer com o novato que não goste de receber esse comentário.

Comment: @Bacco alguma coisa tipo o meu cometário [nesta questão](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15794/7210)?
De qualquer forma votei para fechar até que seja a pergunta alterada.

Comment: @JorgeB. é, acho que esse é o caminho. Fazendo desta forma, quando a pessoa atualizar a questão, podemos remover os comentários obsoletos. O que deu pra perceber fazendo isso é que tem muita gente que entra uma vez no site, e larga a questão lá de qualquer jeito (mesmo com os comentários). Felizmente tem o pessoal que leva a sério e aproveita as indicações. E esses geralmente acabam ajudando os outros da mesma forma depois.

Comment: @JorgeB. Pois é, e o autor teve a boa vontade de tentar melhorar. Se resolveu, não vou me arriscar a dizer, mas ja demonstrou boa vontade :)

Comment: @Bacco acho que foi um bom exemplo de como interagir, realmente. Gostei :)

Answer (score 8):

Eu creio que é pertinente discutir a [existência/presença de moderadores](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1036/a-comunidade-quer-ter-moderadores-proprios) no contexto desta pergunta.

Creio mesmo que as situações mais graves de *guerras de edits*, das quais somente algumas chegaram ao Meta, aconteceram na ausência de um moderador online.

Que diferença faz isso?
O mundo está cheio de injustiças e alguns usuários podem sentir mais fácilmente que outros que o mundo está contra eles. Se não existe moderador que guie e mostre o caminho, até mesmo **convidando e incentivando no momento ao debate para mudar regras**, então existe o perigo de novos utilizadores se sentirem abusados na sua maneira de estar/perguntar.

Em particular, se essa edição que remove os comentários/agradecimentos extra fôr feita por um moderador, ela vai ser aceite mais naturalmente. **A presença de um moderador que explica no momento o porquê das coisas, evita o assunto escalar para por exemplo uma guerra de edits.** O(s) moderador(es) devem também incentivar a discussão sobre a validade de regras estabelecidas, e se esse "convite" fôr feito no momento do edit, ou dos primeiros comentários de indignação em relação a edits, então o usuário sente-se convidado a mudar o sistema e aprende que *a sua voz* pode fazer diferença e é bem vinda no debate.

Eu creio qua a maior parte dos usuários é positiva ao empenhamento da comunidade nos edits e comentários que melhoram perguntas e respostas. Mas ao mesmo tempo é mais ou menos comun usuários acharem que *as raposas velhas* são pouco democráticas ou más hospedes, a meu ver por conclusao precepitada e desconhecimento das boas intenções que por aqui existe. Aí podemos melhorar a coisa comentado mais e melhor **o porquê do edit** e deixar um link para discussôes/debates como este.

Porem eu acho (e daí o foco e contributo que pretendo deixar com esta resposta) que **se o comentário fôr deixado por um moderador, no momento, então as suspeitas nunca se criam**, pequenas suspeitas não viram em sentimentos de abuso, e o novo usuários sente que segurança com a presença dele(s). Isto não implica que deva ser o moderador a fazer os edits. Se fôr tudo bem. O que eu quero dizer é que se uma pergunta começar a aquecer e um moderador que esteja presente no momento a seguir o que acontece, então se ele (moderador) escrever um comentário vai certamente acalmar os ânimos, elevar a discussão para ser menos emocional e caso necessário mudá-la para o meta no momento. Isso tem faltado.

Comment: -1 Porque Eu não concordo com a abordagem, acho que o SOPT tem de ser auto sustentável. Essas guerrinhas estão a acontecer agora de início que ainda estamos muito verdes. Acho que vão se acabando com o tempo. Ainda há-de a ver o dia que ninguém vai editar uma resposta, acreditem. Acho que um moderador era interessante ter, mas não por esse motivo e sim para resolver alguns problemas. Para já acho que o @Gabe dá conta do recado.

Comment: Eu quando era novato não sabia o que o ♦ significava, será que faz diferença de quem vem o comentário?

Comment: @Math mesmo que não faça diferença para os novatos, eu acho que faz aos utilizadores estabelecidos. Quando um moderador está presente isso faz certamente acalmar os ânimos e repensar o que se vai escrever.

Comment: @JorgeB. espero também que isto seja uma transição e que tais "guerrinhas" desapareçam. Porém temo que o que se criem feridas demasiado fundas entre utilizadores e que caminhê-mos para uma comunidade mais polarizada. Eu não concordo que o Gabe dê conta do recado, nem é esse o papel dele como Comunity Manager.

Comment: @JorgeB. O SO existe há 6 anos, tem milhares de perguntas novas por dia, e boa parte são editadas. O privilégio de edição dos usuários que abusam são retirados com frequência lá. Não existe nenhuma razão para achar que aqui os textos vão ficar melhores. Acho que você está um pouco otimista. O moderador é para resolver alguns problemas mesmo. Ainda bem que você sabe que o moderador não vai ficar intervindo em tudo o que aparece no site. E também é para evitar que alguns usuários digam que vão fazer o que bem querem porque não tem moderador.

Comment: @bigown O meu ponto de vista é que um Moderador agora talvez crie um bocado a ideia "temos moderador ele que faça, ele que edite, ele que... etc". Já vi isso a acontecer em muitos lados. E acabava sempre por separar os utilizadores.

Comment: @JorgeB. Isso nunca aconteceu em outros sites da rede. Você pode ter visto em outros lugares que o moderador detêm o poder de fazer tudo. O moderador aqui apenas resolve mais rápido algumas coisas e faz algumas poucas coisas que só ele pode fazer. O moderadores tem algumas funções importantes, mas ele não é o todo poderoso aqui. A comunidade sempre vem em primeiro lugar. Ele só não deixa virar bagunça quando alguma sai realmente do controle. A filosofia aqui incentiva que todos façam e isso sempre funcionou.

Comment: @bigown Sim eu sei disso. Mas o Sergio tem outra ideia de Moderaror, era a isso que me referia. "Por outras palavras, se essa edição que remove os comentários/agradecimentos extra fôr feita por um moderador, ela vai ser aceite mais naturalmente."

Comment: Pelo que percebi da resposta, posso ter percebido mal, mas é a ideia de ter um Moderador que faça algum trabalho em vez da comunidade, para que seja melhor aceite pela mesma.

Comment: @JorgeB. Isso realmente costuma ser o caso. Há vários indícios que moderadores são mais "ouvidos" pelos usuários . Já fui moderador de outro site da rede. Talvez o Sergio possa ter se expressado mal ou você tenha entendido errado, ou eu é que não entendi nada, mas acho que ele também entende que o moderador vai ajudar onde tem problema. A comunidade pode fazer algo (o moderador continua fazendo parte da comunidade), se der problema, o moderador vai lá dar mais autoridade para a ação. Se ele é que fez inicialmente, já é mais difícil dar problema.

Comment: @bigown Se for como explicaste concordo. Não tinha percebido dessa forma.

Comment: @JorgeB. eu vou explicar-me melhor assim que chegar a casa. Mas a ideia é, como o bigown referiu, que o moderador ajude quando os problemas surgem e no momento. Não quero também, como você, que os edits acabem sendo feitos só por moderadores. Eu refiro-me à presença porque gera tranquilidade, não necessáriamente porquê é ele que tem de fazer e justificar os edits. Vou corrigir daqui a pouco para ficar mais claro.

Comment: @JorgeB., editei a resposta para ficar mais clara. Espero que esteja melhor nesse aspeto de clareza e que seja mais fácil assim concordar ou discordar dela.

Comment: +1 Concordo agora com a nova edição.

Answer (score 4):

> Eu, por exemplo, sempre gostei da ideia de ensinar através de edições (removendo cumprimentos, formatando código, melhorando o texto). Foi algo que aconteceu comigo quando comecei a usar o SO (5 anos atrás) e que apreciei na época. Era uma forma de me ensinar sem ter que me chamar a atenção.
>
> Botei isso em prática no SOPT, preferindo editar à deixar um comentário chamando a atenção e esperando que o autor corrigisse. Até que vi alguém dizendo no Meta que considerava isso invasivo e autoritário. Então talvez minha impressão de que esse método é efetivo esteja errada...
>
> Talvez seja melhor apenas o comentario? Talvez seja melhor editar e comentar? Talvez seja melhor permitir algumas coisas a mais no nosso primeiro ano? Não sei.

Algumas observações adicionais quanto às edições:

- Quando era iniciante no Stack Overflow, eu não sabia que era possível ver o histórico de edições, então tentava adivinhar o que havia sido mudado e por que razão. Pode até ser vergonhoso, mas eu levei meses para descobrir o link do histórico.
- Há edições que não têm resumo ou que têm resumo pouco explicativo;
- O Stack Overflow prefere edições globais que melhorem um post inteiro de uma única vez em vez de uma série de edições pequenas. Uma das consequências dessa tática é que fica mais complicado escrever um resumo que descreva tudo o que foi alterado — por exemplo, com links para posts do meta explicando os motivos —, bem como relacionar edições específicas com partes do resumo.

Esses fatores diluem o potencial didático das edições. Acho que comentários funcionam melhor do que os resumos das edições por serem mais visíveis. Por outro lado, poluem mais justamente por serem mais visíveis.

Comment: Eu também demorei para descobrir o histórico das edições, mas tb acho que comentar não é uma boa, pq acaba virando um pate papo

Comment: @Math em adoraria comentar para ensinar, mas realmente tem o efeito colateral de criar atrito com quem gosta de atrito. Quando raramente eu escrevo algo, o usuário acaba me criar arrependimento. O Gabe já me disse que ficar comentando para mostrar para o usuário como ele deve ser comportar não adianta nada. Então eu mudei minha postura. Bavarious: Existem essas duas correntes. Como atender as duas necessidades, os usuários que não gostam que ensinem eles (talvez achem que estão levando bronca) e os que acham que isso é didático? Se perguntar para ele qual a preferência, já escolheu um lado.

Comment: Concordo com avisar o autor sempre que possível em vez de mexer, quando for pergunta. Aí se não houver retorno depois de um tempo razoável, ok (a não ser que o treco tenha algum problema sério demais). Em respostas eu tenho evitado mexer e até comentar, pois infelizmente parte da "nova geração" tem o problema de "nunca estar errada", e aí um comentário que você faz para dar oportunidade da pessoa melhorar vira uma briga eterna. Nota: não estou falando de um ou dois users, estou falando de um punhado, e de coisas que acontecem com todos, não só comigo. (antes que a história inverta de novo)

Comment: Quanto a poluir, sempre que o autor lê uma sugestão de edição minha, aceitando ou não, eu sempre apago depois (exceto por esquecimento).

Comment: @Bacco Resposta eu raramente edito. E mudo coisas pontuais, não vou mudar o sentido do que a pessoa respondeu. Pergunta eu edito bastante. Estou tentando ajudar a pergunta dele para ele e para todos. A pergunta não é só dele, é da comunidade. Tem que ajudar todo mundo. É, demora para os novatos entenderem isso, mas é isso que nos diferencia, se mudar coisas como essa, não somos mais SE. Quando o usuário quer por qualquer motivo psicológico dele que a pergunta permaneça intacta, ele não está preocupado com a comunidade. Em perguntas muda bastante, mas **nunca o sentido**.

Comment: São raras as vezes que não deixo um [resumo de edição explicativo](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/201/brasofilo?tab=activity&sort=revisions). E se o usuário é novato aproveito para deixar dicas ali. Pode ser que leiam, pode ser que não, mas acredito que é uma mostra de respeito pelo autor/a do post "olha, modifiquei seu texto por causa disso e daquilo outro".

Answer (score 4):

Na minha humilde opinião quem pensa que editar um post é algo invasivo nunca participou ativamente de um fórum público convencional onde a grande massa de usuários é composta de pessoas as quais escrevem errado de propósito, por pura preguiça.

Já participo do Stack Overflow há um tempo, mas mais pra sanar algumas dúvidas cabeludas que nenhum fórum nacional podia fazê-lo.

Migrei de um fórum de TI grande no Brasil, o qual durante muito tempo teve um excelente fluxo de conteúdo mas que por descaso passou a ser um local onde questões duplicadas e mal redigidas eram aceitas, respondidas pelos próprios Moderadores copiando e colando respostas (ao invés de apontar onde a resposta estava e trancar o tópico) e ainda por cima reputação positiva era dada em quantidades estratosféricas, para os padrões de um fórum.

[Inicialmente](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/846/saudacoes-e-agradecimentos) fui parcialmente contra Saudações e Agradecimentos de serem removidos mas refletindo com mais calma percebi que tal imperativismo era apenas aparente, implicância de minha parte.

Azedume pessoal à parte, eu relacionaria os seguintes:

- Sempre vejo stacks de PHP sendo editados onde possível. Talvez seja impressão mas as tags associadas não estão recebendo a mesma atenção.

  Já vi, por exemplo, stacks recentes em que a dúvida é 98% JavaScript porque o autor achou que AJAX iria curar o câncer de sua aplicação, mas só porque tem lá um URL apontando para um arquivo PHP, a dita tag aparece junto.

  Parece bobagem, mas se é dispendido tempo para fazer uma revisão orto-gramatical além da contextualização, que mal há em remover uma tag-zinha errada ou mal colocada?
- Elaborar melhor a Ajuda sobre "O que não postar". Por exemplo, eu gostaria de perguntar algo sobre um determinado plugin JavaScript há tempos, mas estou receoso de fazê-lo justamente porque a(s) resposta(s) poderia(m) ser muito vaga(s) ou subjetiva(s) em execesso.
- Supondo que não seja feito dessa forma hoje, sugeriria também que stacks/comentários sinalizados fossem revistos por mais de uma pessoa.

  Até o presente momento fiz uma única sinalização a qual foi rejeitada. Não estou reclamando da decisão, mas o motivo da rejeição, além de estar em inglês (não que tenha sido um problema), ao meu ver não foi de todo correta pois a partir do momento que um código é postado errado, apesar de ser um problema técnico, ele deixa de ser proveitoso e, conforme dita a descrição, justifica ser sinalizado.
- Fora isso, acho que resta apenas melhorias na tradução do site. Ainda vejo **em suspenso** quando deveria ser simplesmente **supenso** ou, até mesmo nesse stack o uso do termo "Pilha".

  Certo, certo, "Stack" significa "Pilha", mas cá entre nós, essa tradução em particular está sendo motivo de chacota em outros sites de desenvolvimento os quais frequento. Não que isso possa ferir a reputação do SOPT, mas, de novo, se é pra fazer, que façamos bom e melhoremos até ser ótimo.

Comment: Quanto ao ponto dois é simples, perguntas, tentas ser o menos subjetivo possível. Mas nunca tenhas medo de perguntar. Se estiver bem elaborada duvido que votem para fechar, e se votarem já ficas a saber.

Comment: Muito bom. Complementando: eu compreendo a dificuldade dos novatos de entenderem nosso modelo e é bom acharmos uma forma de melhorara isso. Ponto. O que questiono é se devemos agradar aqueles que tiveram tempo para refletir e decidiram que este modelo não é bom (tendo refletido ou não). Não podemos controlar o que cada um pensa. Algumas explicações: eu vejo mesmo muitas tags eradas. Quando eu tenho certeza eu mudo (às vezes faço retags em massa), mas não mexo em algo que tenho dúvidas, seja por falta de conhecimento meu, seja porque a pergunta não está tão clara se é aquilo. ...

Comment: Faça a pergunta que quer. Se esforce para deixar ela o melhor possível, mostre que ela é importante e tente melhorá-la com o *feedback*. Se ele tiver que ser fechada mesmo, paciência, não é o fim do mundo ter uma pergunta fechada. Teste a comunidade. Coloque link para a rejeição, se for possível. Mostre pra gente onde há chacota. Pode por links externos aqui. Aqui não tem a regra que "concorrentes" não podem ser referenciados (a não ser para preservá-los).

Comment: Seria tão mais fácil controlar as mentes das pessoas... Não, Brainiac, agora não, pára... (cough) Prefiro não postar onde eu vi isso. Não só por questões éticas, mas também porque não foi nada formal, foi só bate-papo num clone mal feito do recurso de atualizações de status que Facebutts tem.

Answer (score 3):

Quando ingressei no SO, imaginava que ♦ significava top user. Talvez alguém com mais reputação que os outros, não necessariamente um moderador. Além do que, moderadores no SO, pelo menos nas perguntas sobre Delphi não costumam surgir muito.

Não acho que seja hora de termos moderadores da comunidade. A maioria dos nossos *"líderes comunitários"* se conhecem desde o início e a impressão que tenho é que estes têm pensamentos alinhados em muitas áreas, talvez áreas demais.

Acho que com o tempo, chegarão novos usuários, eles eventualmente se tornarão avançados e estes um dia se tornarão também líderes comunitários e nesse momento estaremos prontos para eleições.

Uma eleição hoje seria como se tivéssemos vários candidatos de um só partido, restando aos usuários escolher o mais carismático dono da mesma filosofia.
[image: A ilusão da escolha]

Comment: Me dá a impressão que você está sugerindo que a eleição deve ser com aqueles que te simpatizam, pois os atuais não servem. Pode acontecer de quando você chegar neste dia, alguém vir aqui e falar "os top users atuais não tem o mínimo alinhamento, então não é hora de eleições", da mesma forma. Quanto a se conhecerem desde o início, não é o que as estatísticas do Area 51 mostram, pois uma significante parte do pessoal aqui é "novidade".

Comment: @Bacco a existência da minha simpatia ou a falta dela nada têm a ver com o fato de, mais uma vez, ao meu ver, existir apenas "um partido" na briga e isso se torna uma democracia falsa. E pra mim, se é pra votar de mentirinha, o melhor é nem votar. Ao contrario do que sugeriu seu comentário, a diversidade, por mais que não concordemos com a maioria das opiniões é necessária, pois ninguém é dono da verdade e nenhuma filosofia é totalmente certa, portanto, para que possamos escolher, esperemos que pelo menos hajam escolhas.

Comment: Exatamente, temos muitos users, e você não vê escolha, percebe o que eu quero dizer? E veja o que são moderadores pro-tempore, isso foi discutido no meta varias vezes. São temporários, até esse momento de poder eleger.

Comment: @Bacco realmente. Apenas um apontamento: Não é que não vejo escolha, gosto muito do comprometimento de alguns usuários com relação a isso e os teria como moderadores aqui com o maior orgulho, o problema é que a comunidade ainda é muito jovem e talvez por isso, a palavra panelinha não consiga sair da minha cabeça.

Comment: Eu humildemente acho é que essa palavra foi meio que "programada" na sua cabeça dadas as discussões que o pessoal andou tendo aqui. Panelinha seriam pessoas que se combinam no mesmo sentido, e isto eu tenho visto os novatos fazendo em busca de voto, "me vota que eu te voto", e coisas assim (este foi só um exemplo). O que infelizmente as pessoas não entendem, é que se por acaso um grupo com uma certa experiência decide em um sentido, pode ser realmente por aquele ser o caminho melhor na análise da experiência. Aí quem pensa ao contrário tende a ver complô onde não existe. Aqui acontece direto.

Comment: Mais um problema: hoje temos UM moderador, que é o Gabe. Percebe que aí o julgamento passa por ele apenas? Com dois ou mais poderiamos ter diferenças de pensamento, saudáveis para o site. Com um só, a visão é polarizada, e as atividades de moderação e community-manager sobrecarregam ele a ponto de que as respostas de moderação acabam sendo lentas no site quando ocorrem problemas pontuais. Isso não é culpa dele, mas sim da falta de gente pra estar "corujando" o site e jogando balde de agua fria nos desentendimentos.

Comment: @Filipe.Fonseca Eu entendo que o SOpt é diferente, ainda não entendi totalmente o que isso significa, mas claramente é diferente. Mas tem comunidades mais jovens que tiveram moderadores logo. Comunidades menores que a nossa que possuem bem mais que 3 moderadores. Isso dá diversidade. Poque ter 1 moderador, que na verdade é CM, é melhor que ter 3 da comunidade + 1 da SE? Por outro lado se a diversidade for muito grande, fica contraprodutivo. Eu vejo a adição de moderadores uma forma da SE conseguir aliados para resolver os poucos problemas que faltam. Parece que a SE vê diferente.

Comment: :D Vai parecer panelinha :D Eu escrevi o mesmo antes de ler o do Bacco, e não combinei nada com ele. Claro que não adianta nada falar isso para os adeptos de teorias de conspiração :)

Comment: Concordo em todos os pontos levantados nos últimos dois comentários. Mas a opinião dos prováveis candidatos, pelo que lí no tópico de votação, também está polarizada. Talvez um CM auxiliando o @Gabe já seria o suficiente, pois ainda não temos um candidato com uma terceira proposta.

Comment: E se temos apenas um polo, a votação se torna puramente carismática, como dito na resposta.

Comment: @Filipe.Fonseca lembrando do que eu comentei, pode ser um "pro-tempore", que depois seja substituido. Lembre-se de que o Gabe já tem uma visão diferente dos candidatos lá, então teríamos dois polos. E o Gabe é o CM (community-manager). De qq forma o(s) moderador(es) se reportam ao Gabe, aqui não é igual fórum e canal de IRC, que moderador esculacha com usuário.

Comment: @bacco é. A palavra moderador realmente traz essa bagagem do IRC. Dessa forma acho válido.

Comment: @Filipe.Fonseca talvez esteja um pouco defasado, mas é ótimo pra entender a filosofia: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/

Comment: Como já disse o Bacco, poderia haver moderadores *pro-tempore*, escolhidos pela Stack Exchange. Se fosse para ter eleições agora, tem duas coisas que parecem não estar claras para você: (1) qualquer usuário pode se candidatar, então pode aparecer todo tipo de gente, de vários "partidos"; (2) em geral as eleições são para escolher mais de um moderador, e sites novos costumam começar com 3 moderadores.

Comment: @bfavaretto a (2) eu entendi muito bem, mas quanto à (1) tenho minhas dúvidas, afinal, qualquer cristão pode ser papa mas nem por isso meu nome aparece na lista do conclave.

Comment: Ok Filipe, é sua resposta dava a entender que talvez você não estivesse ciente dessas coisas. A diferença com o conclave é que aqui você pode aparecer na lista. Se vai ter muitos votos ou não, depende da sua relação com a comunidade.

Comment: @bfavaretto no fim do dia, sabemos os 5~6 nomes que terão condições de receber voto, eu saberia exatamente em quais 3 destes votar, mas por razões pura e simplesmente carismáticas, uma vez que percebo (minha opinião) as ideias e os pensamentos destes "sempre" seguindo pelo mesmo caminho. Caminho que concordo, diga-se de passagem, mas ainda assim é só uma ilusão de escolha.

Comment: @bfavaretto não almejo tal posição, gostaria de ter o tempo necessário para um trabalho tão importante, mas mesmo que tivesse não acho que tenha perfil pra "líder comunitário"(infelizmente)

Comment: @bfavaretto Não discordo da filosofia do site, inclusive, tanto concordo que cessei minha contribuição no SO conforme fui conhecendo o SOP. Gosto da comunidade e concordo com a maioria das regras discutidas. Toda a polêmica surgiu porque falei que embora eu concorde com o rumo que estamos seguindo, acho saudável para o site que tenhamos eleições mais heterogêneas. Quando me mostraram sobre os moderadores "pro-tempore" cortei a discussão no mesmo instante, pois achei um modelo que me pareceu justo.

Comment: Certo Filipe, eu não contesto nada disso, e fico feliz em saber que você gosta do site e da comunidade. Realmente sua afirmação sobre o "partido único" é polêmica, embora seja *parcialmente* verdadeira.

Answer (score 2):

Eu já postei uma "resposta", mas lendo as demais respostas e comentários, me deu vontade de compartilhar mais... e o lugar para fazer isso é aqui (pois não cabe num comentário e não pertence a outro lugar). Portanto, lá vou eu...

...mas antes de focar no assunto em pauta, quero compartilhar que encaro minhas opiniões como **opiniões**; se no que se refere a *código* eu posso por a mão no fogo por uma determinada ***afirmação***, o mesmo não vale para uma **opinião**. Por exemplo: `$i = 5; echo $i++ . ++$i;` - qual o *output* disso? (PHP) Apesar de não ser nada pessoal, eu poderia ficar furioso se alguém discordasse que o *output* é `57`. É algo objetivo e indiscutível. É `57` e ponto final! **Não** se trata de **opinião**. Por outro lado, há várias questões que envolvem muito a subjetividade e **opiniões**. Eu gosto sim de discutir aqui no Meta e tratar de confrontar **opiniões** - mas, paradoxalmente, mesmo sendo "pessoal", eu nunca vou "levar pro pessoal" (não sei se esta expressão comum no Brasil faz sentido em Portugal) - em outras palavras, eu não tendo a me ofender ou ficar furioso quando houver discordância em **opinião**, pois a partir da formação cultural, espiritual, acadêmica, social, profissional, parental, e todas as demais influências no desenvolvimento da personalidade de cada um, é formada uma **perspectiva individual** sobre determinados assuntos. Ou seja: em questão de **opinião** não tem "**certo**" ou "**errado**" - eu posso fincar pé e argumentar enfaticamente a favor da minha opinião, e eu também posso dar ouvidos e refletir sobre a opinião diferente vinda de outra pessoa, buscando compreender de onde ela vem - qual a perspectiva que a justifica.

Dito isso, sigo adiante, manifestando minhas meras **opiniões**, minha limitada visão particular individual sobre os assuntos levantados, tentando contribuir e também atendendo ao chamado por opiniões que foi feito aqui. Nem sei por onde eu **começo**! :-)

---

1º - Existe uma preocupação com a imagem do site:

> Houve [...] reclamações do site ser muito rígido [...] me fez pensar
>   na primeira imagem que nós passamos aos recém-chegados [...] em termos
>   [...] de comportamento.

2º - Existe uma busca de soluções objetivas:

> Talvez seja melhor apenas o comentario? Talvez seja melhor editar e
>   comentar? Talvez seja melhor permitir algumas coisas a mais no nosso
>   primeiro ano?

3º - Existem alguns anseios:

> Precisamos que as pessoas sejam bem recebidas aqui.

4º - E dúvidas:

> Como podemos melhorar isso? Onde podemos melhorar?

Eu mesmo não concordo 100% com a minha própria opinião :-) ...eu sei que ela é parcial... mas eu preciso manifestar a minha perspectiva de alguma maneira, e é por isso que o faço, com todas as suas imperfeições:

A essência da questão sendo colocada aqui é muito mais profunda do que se parece ou que se pretende admitir. Eu gostaria de saber a estatística de quantas **mulheres** utilizam o Stack Overflow. Eu queria saber se essa proporção é a mesma do que as profissionais na área, ou se, como me parece, a preponderância masculina na comunidade é muito superior do que a preponderância já existente no próprio mercado de trabalho. Aonde estão as mulheres? Será que o SO reflete uma cultura machista?

Eu não penso isso. Eu estou convidando à reflexão. Só que não é uma reflexão ordinária. É uma reflexão profunda - e o tópico aqui **é** profundo. O próprio fato de não se tolerar certas reflexões e essa **urgência por soluções práticas**, objetividade, *get things done*, remover saudações, remover questões subjetivas, essa ânsia por *guidelines*, regras, padrões, dogmas... fala sério, pessoal - às vezes parece que perdemos a noção do ridículo.

Como já disse, e redisse, eu não "assino embaixo" do que estou escrevendo - estou só *água mole em pedra dura*... tentando mostrar que as coisas têm **dois lados**... YIN e YANG, preto e branco, masculino e feminino...

Pois bem. Então SO já se posicionou que é YANG, objetivo, direto, sem enrolações, sem "bom dia" e "boa noite" (frescuras de madame, encheção de linguiça), é pé no chão, resolve problemas, faz, acontece, UAU! SO é sexy, é musculoso, malhado. Revisar isso seria auto-traição, voltar para trás, perder terreno. Se eu tivesse o mínimo vocabulário de psicologia poderia enriquecer minha manifestação com termos mais eloquentes - mas me falta essa erudição.

Portanto, queridos, humildemente tentando contribuir e quiçá responder as questões aqui levantadas, acho que a resposta e o convite vão no sentido de uma auto-análise dos membros participantes...

> Precisamos que as pessoas sejam bem recebidas aqui.
>   Talvez seja melhor apenas o comentario? Talvez seja melhor editar e
>   comentar? Talvez seja melhor permitir algumas coisas a mais no nosso
>   primeiro ano?
>   Como podemos melhorar isso? Onde podemos melhorar?

A **conduta correta**, ou ***dharma***, em sânscrito, dá margem a extensas considerações filosóficas. Paradoxalmente, se resume a:

> Não faça aos outros aquilo que não gostaria que fizessem com você.

Outra forma de elaborar seria:

> Antes de agir, considere a intenção que move a ação, e veja se é prejudicial a algum envolvido. Caso seja, não torne o impulso em ação. Economize essa energia para que seja melhor utilizada em outra ocasião.

Estamos no campo da ética e da moral... Sim, estamos! Essa obsessão pelas respostas definitivas, práticas e objetivas, essa ânsia por um algoritmo replicável em todas as situações... cada um pode analisar de onde vem isso em si mesmo. Porque até um ponto equilibrado, é saudável. Mas, além desse ponto, é patológico!

A voz da maioria irá sempre pesar em prol dessa vertente "YANG", porque é próprio de "YANG" manifestar-se, enquanto é próprio de "YIN" submeter-se, calar-se.

---

#### SOpt não é SO...

Então... eu vislumbro uma "revolução"... enquanto o SO mostrou um padrão "São Miguel Guerreiro", com sua espada audaz cortando e removendo qualquer "ofensa" à Absoluta Objetividade... de repente chegam os lusófonos, mais cuca-fresca, menos "Get Things Done", masculino, YANG, objetivo, pé-no-chão, e conseguem fazer da mesma plataforma algo menos paranóico e mais humano.

> Precisamos que as pessoas sejam bem recebidas aqui.
>   Como podemos melhorar isso? Onde podemos melhorar?

Óia, aqui em Minas, a gente dá pão de queijo e cafézinho, e costuma dá muito certo. Conhecem aquela do Gaúcho e do Mineiro? O mineiro foi no boteco, lá no Rio Grande do Sul, e tava rolando muito vinho, cerveja, o pessoal animado... aí ele chegou e pediu um copo de **leite**! Então o gauchão falou alto e grosso: "aqui a gente não gosta de homem que bebe leite!" E então o mineiro respondeu do seu jeitim: "êita... lá em Minas a gente não gosta de homem de jeito nenhum, uai!" :-)

[off-topic] Eu tenho que ir buscar as crianças na escola, pessoal. Depois eu volto.

---

#### Continuando

Se o problema é "comportamento", na medida que o comportamento **de cada um** melhorar, o "comportamento do *site*" irá melhorar...

Eu já frequentei certos grupos com regras bem claras e definidas - e neles havia o mesmo "dilema" da "melhor forma" de recepcionar os novatos. E havia também o perfil "porrete", que não perdoava o mais inocente deslize por simples desconhecimento da regra, reagindo de forma rude - até o perfil "gentileza", delicadamente chamando a atenção após ter conquistado previamente a simpatia do interlocutor. É interessante ver o mesmo padrão de problemática no mundo virtual.

Finalmente, o que eu penso que cada um pode fazer para melhorar o site é, dentro do possível, **se dedicar mais a fazer boas perguntas e respostas sobre programação** do que quaisquer outras tarefas. E, ao interferir na ação de outros usuários, **prezar pela cordialidade MAIS do que pela aplicação de regras**. As regras são importantes, mas o lado humano é **mais** importante. Esta é a minha opinião.

P.S. - a partir do *feedback* já recebido - eu acho que o SOpt está indo bem; inclusive, pessoalmente, em nenhum momento me senti hostilizado aqui, de maneira nenhuma; pelo contrário: mesmo com opiniões divergentes, a discussão é civilizada, inteligente, madura; acho que está de parabéns. Dá para melhorar? Claro que sim. Sempre dá para melhorar. O código que a gente escreveu há poucos meses, a gente sabe que se for escrever de novo, escrevia de um jeito diferente (e melhor), não é mesmo?

Comment: Você acha que este site está no ponto patológico do desequilíbrio? Até concordo que falta YIN, mas acho que não estamos tão bitolados, ansiosos e sem noção do ridículo assim...

Comment: Não, eu não acho. Acho que está indo bem. É só uma "manifestação", fruto do convite à reflexão, convidando a mais reflexão.

Comment: Toma meu voto por questionar a naturalidade do pensamento masculino de objetividade absoluta que impera. Só discordo da binaridade homem x mulher e não entendo o suficiente das culturas orientais para saber se tá falando besteira sobre Yin & Yang e dharma só para montar o argumento. =P

Comment: Obrigado! Sinceramente, não entendo o que seja "discordar da binaridade homem x mulher". Quanto aos termos orientais, creio não estar falando besteira - porém nada nessa resposta deve ser levado muito a sério, ou melhor, é para ser levado a sério sim, mas com leveza, sem peso, com bom humor. Penso que podemos discutir este assunto, preservando sua seriedade mas de forma alegre, descontraída.

Comment: Discordar da binaridade homem x mulher é só reconhecer que existem outros gêneros. Ao criticar um comportamento predominantemente masculino, não quer dizer que se esteja defendendo uma alternativa feminina, e sim uma alternativa não-masculina.

Comment: +1 acho que disse tudo, uma boa resposta de reflexão.

Comment: Sobre a presença de mulheres no site, apareceu uma discussão relacionada no MSE: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254891/do-you-think-that-the-perceived-sex-of-the-poster-factors-into-whether-less-than

Answer (score 2):

Ótima postagem. Concordo em diversos pontos.

O Stack Overflow em inglês é rígido, semana passada fiz uma pergunta lá, talvez eu não tenha sido muito claro, em dois minutos já tinha pontos negativos e a pergunta foi categorizada como 'off-topic'. Fui revisar a minha pergunta e havia alguns erros de concordância no inglês (sou intermediário ainda).

No SOPT já cometi erros parecidos, mas os próprios usuários, educadamente, me indicaram revisões no texto, o qual apliquei e a pergunta permaneceu sem ser negativada.
Eu acho que essa visão 'rígida' segue o caminho do Stack Overflow original.

Comment: Não percebi se preferes a visão 'rígida' ou a versão mais 'educada'...

Comment: Nem é questão de preferir, foi apenas uma observação mesmo.
Mas, acho que nós brasileiros, podemos seguir como estamos.

Comment: Ou seja: não estamos tão rígidos como no site em inglês, certo? Bom você dizer isso, porque às vezes o Gabe encasqueta que eu e outros usuários queremos ter aqui um site exatamente como o SO original, o que não é verdade.

Comment: @JorgeB. Não sei se te entendi mas não parece que rigidez e e educação são conceitos opostos. Na verdade flexibilidade demais pode ser sinal de falta de educação. Por exemplo, por mais que esteja bem intencionado, chegar na casa de alguém e fazer o que bem entende é uma flexibilidade que pode ser considerada educada? Concordo com o Felipe Stoker, não aceitamos qualquer coisa aqui, mas procuramos ajudar. Eu mesmo tenho visto casos de atitudes lá no SO que não ajudam o site. Aqui estamos tentando evitar isso. Só falta achar o ponto que ajuda mais. Porque aceitar tudo também não ajuda.

Comment: @bigown foi por isso que pus entre aspas as duas expressões. Tentei ser minimalista mas foi pior a emenda que o soneto :D
O que eu queria dizer é se prefere a versão de "vamos ajudar sim senhor" ou "corta-se o mal pela raiz". Se é que me faço entender...

Comment: @JorgeB. Entendi. O que parece que alguns não entendem (ninguém em especial) é que algumas pessoas confundem educação com automatismo. Apertar a mão ou beijar em algumas culturas é falta de educação. Em um site sério de perguntas e respostas é educado (sem exageros) se preocupar com ortografia, gramática, clareza, organização, tentar algo antes de perguntar, não colocar textos que são puro ruído, que não ajudam a pergunta ou mesmo a resposta. Não seguir isso é falta de educação mesmo quando a pessoa acha que está sendo educada.

Comment: O que acontece é que vivemos em países diferentes e a nossa cultura e educação na internet é totalmente diferente. Acho que está bom assim, não precisa ser tão 'frio' (é assim que imagino) como os americanos.

Answer (score 1):

Uma vez, no SO em inglês, eu cliquei em "***edit***" para editar um *typo* (erro de digitação) grosseiro. Porém, para minha surpresa, como se *alguém* "do outro lado" tivesse poderes de vidência e pré-cognição, surgiu uma mensagem enfática, direta e objetiva, a qual eu gostaria de reproduzir *ipsis litteris* aqui, porém não consegui localizá-la.

O recado, em suma, era que **edições insignificantes eram desencorajadas**. A mensagem, no caso, parecia "vidente" porque dizia mais ou menos assim: "se você veio editar apenas para corrigir um *typo*, então deixe a postagem como está; apenas faça alterações se elas forem realmente fazer diferença".

O impacto dessa experiência foi bem forte e inesquecível para mim. Nunca mais perdi o meu tempo, dos revisores, moderadores, *etc*, com "trivialidades". Ao ver um *typo* no SO em inglês, minha reação passou a ser: "ah, é só um *typo*".

---

Tentando encontrar a mensagem referida, encontrei foi [a opinião de um dos fundadores do Stack Overflow, Jeff Atwood](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/82873/149253).

À época da referida opinião, 2011, ele era o manda-chuva lá, e estava não só ordenando mas como implementando ele mesmo regras mais restritivas para impedir o surgimento dessas mini-edições.

No meu entendimento, Jeff Atwood está certo, e a quantidade de tempo e discussão dispendidas para trivialidades e coisas sem importância é imenso. Por isso, penso como ele - edições que não vão fazer diferença nenhuma para o conteúdo deveriam ser desencorajadas.

Comment: Sou bem adepto disso que ele menciona: "yes, there is an exception when a single character like a semicolon makes code wrong, but again -- is everything else in that post so perfect it cannot be improved? I doubt it.". Concordo que é melhor não mexer por bobeira, mas se é pra mexer, já analise arrume tudo, em vez de mexer em uma ou duas coisinhas e largar o resto dos problemas como está. E se não tem condição de melhorar, melhor não mexer.

Comment: Concordo @Bacco