# Como tirar melhor proveito da análise de "Primeiras Publicações"

Tags: debate, filas-de-análise

Estava lendo um post do metão ([How can we make First Posts review actually useful?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234153/how-can-we-make-first-posts-review-actually-useful)) e lembrei do post do Gabe há um tempo ([Estado da Pilha #1: Carinho](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1333/estado-da-pilha-1-carinho)) e pensei.

Poderia haver um consenso do que fazer com os posts da fila de primeiras publicações, para que ela seja bem aproveitada o autor de sua primeira publicação, tenha nesta fila um primeiro norteamento.

Um ponto interessante colocado no post citado é que, para votar a favor, um OP precisa de 15 pontos de reputação, o que são 3 upvotes. Não sei quantos revisores são necessários para uma primeira publicação sair da fila, mas uma boa pergunta já poderia render para ele estes pontos.

Uma coisa que também seria interessante é que a pergunta postada só ficasse pública após a revisão. Várias vezes as revisões de primeiras publicações aparecem depois de já ter comentários e edições.

Algumas idéias que achei interessantes:

## Editar

Se a pergunta ficou quase boa, não acho que precisaria fazer o autor tentar reescrever, apenas realizar os ajustes e comentar que alterou para facilitar a compreensão

## Comentar

Se não ficou claro, antes de fechar ou sinalizar, recomendar ao autor ler os posts da **Central de Ajuda** e **Como Perguntar**, pedir mais informações

## Votar

Se a pergunta está de uma forma que é possível de se responder, vote, é um apoio para outros operadores se interessarem por ela e o autor ficar contente com a comunidade

## Formatar

Ajustar a formatação e simplesmente deixar como comentário da revisão. Pode ser que o operador não conheça a ferramenta, mas tendo sua publicação formatada, ele já passa a entender o que fazer da próxima vez.

Acho que o que não vale a pena é votar para fechar ou sinalizar logo no início de sua  primeira publicação, exceto casos mais graves.

O que vocês acham sobre?

Comment: Não creio que pode haver com consenso pois a análise de uma primeira publicação é muito subjetiva e pode variar enormemente em qualidade. No entanto, eu sempre dou o benefício da dúvida. Se não tenho certeza que ela é ruim o suficiente para ser fechada ou votada contra e não entendo do assunto simplesmente deixo ela lá até ver a reação de outros usuários.

Comment: @utluiz Não quis chegar ao ponto de um consenso de todos fazerem a mesma coisa, mas de tentar tirar um maior proveito desta fila de análise para melhorar a retenção de usuário que acabam fazendo uma pergunta e acabam se desinteressando pela comunidade

Comment: Claro, eu entendo e concordo com você. Só fiz alguns comentários para colocar meu ponto de vista porque estou sem tempo agora para dar uma resposta mais completa.

Comment: Acho legais as idéias delineadas +1

Comment: Primeiras publicações também inclui respostas, você focou quase que exclusivamente nas perguntas.

Comment: `Não sei quantos revisores são necessários para uma primeira publicação sair da fila` Respondendo, é necessário apenas um revisor.